# ASP.NET MVC IIS request.files doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Request.Files doesn't work when I deploy to the server but it works when I test locally. What do I need to configure to make this work when deployed?

Comment: Can you please show us the code - for example if this is a file upload, the form and input being used to upload the file and the code in your controller that is attempting to process the upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) from Phil Haack can be useful for you:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Note that here you do not examine the `Request.Files` collection. Also example for the multiple file upload can be found there (main idea that you should use the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` in similar manner).

Answer (score 2):

Some example of your code would be nice, but this post helped me once:

[A Back To Basics Case Study: Implementing HTTP File Upload with ASP.NET MVC including Tests and Mocks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Comment: Can you bring some content here?